# multiple sort in an xml using xslt

Tags: php, xml, xslt-1.0

I'm trying to sort two xml file in order to compare them with winmerge but i've got an issue when i manage to sort the node but i also need to sort multiple attribute with the same name.

Here is my xml :

```
<node>
  <location>A</location>
  <title>folder in A</title>
  <acl group="group_4" permissions="111111111"/>
  <acl group="group_2" permissions="110000000"/>
  <acl group="group_3" permissions="110000000"/>
  <acl group="group_1" permissions="110000000"/>
</node>
<node>
  <location>A</location>
  <title>Another folder in A</title>
  <acl group="group_1" permissions="110000000"/>
  <acl group="group_3" permissions="111111111"/>
  <acl group="group_2" permissions="110000000"/>
</node>
```

my xsl look like this :

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8" />
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="import/node">
      <xsl:sort select="location" data-type="text" order="ascending"/>
      <xsl:sort select="title[not(@clear)]" data-type="text" order="ascending"/>
      <xsl:sort select="@group" data-type="text" order="ascending"/>
      <node>
        <xsl:copy-of select="location"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="title[not(@clear)]"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="acl[not(@basegroup) and not(@baseowner) and not(@standard)]"/>
      </node>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and i've got this result :

```
<node>
  <location>A</location>
  <title>Another folder in A</title>
  <acl group="group_1" permissions="110000000"/>
  <acl group="group_3" permissions="111111111"/>
  <acl group="group_2" permissions="110000000"/>
</node>
<node>
  <location>A</location>
  <title>folder in A</title>
  <acl group="group_4" permissions="111111111"/>
  <acl group="group_2" permissions="110000000"/>
  <acl group="group_3" permissions="110000000"/>
  <acl group="group_1" permissions="110000000"/>
</node>
```

instead of this one :

```
<node>
  <location>A</location>
  <title>Another folder in A</title>
  <acl group="group_1" permissions="110000000"/>
  <acl group="group_2" permissions="110000000"/>
  <acl group="group_3" permissions="111111111"/>
</node>
<node>
  <location>A</location>
  <title>folder in A</title>
  <acl group="group_1" permissions="110000000"/>
  <acl group="group_2" permissions="110000000"/>
  <acl group="group_3" permissions="110000000"/>
  <acl group="group_4" permissions="111111111"/>
</node>
```

I've already check into similar post but nothing work. Thanks in advance. Best regards.

Comment: Your example is not clear. It seems like you want to sort the `node` elements by `location` and by `title` and then, **within each node**, sort the `act` elements by the `group` attribute. What you are actually doing is trying to sort the `node` elements by a `group` attribute which they don't have.

Comment: Hello michael, you're right, I try to sort the node elements by location and title and then in each node order the acl attribute. Do I need to create a temporary group in order to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to sort the `acl` elements separately, within an `xsl:for-each` (or `xsl:apply-templates`) instruction of their own - something like:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8" />

<xsl:template match="/import">
    <xsl:for-each select="node">
        <xsl:sort select="location" data-type="text" order="ascending"/>
        <xsl:sort select="title" data-type="text" order="ascending"/>
        <node>
            <xsl:copy-of select="location | title"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="acl">
                <xsl:sort select="@group" data-type="text" order="ascending"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            </xsl:for-each> 
        </node>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Have a nice day. Best regards